# Jenkins Build Issues - File INSTALL cannot find /obj-x86_64-linux-gnu

Tags: ros, jenkins, deb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Still having trouble with building packages... This time, it seems that the issue is almost resolved, however. The build seems successful (as far as I can tell); however, the `cmake_install.cmake` file causes make to fail. Does anyone see the issue?

```
Install the project...
/usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-p2os-teleop-1.0.1-0raring-20130723-0625/debian/ros-hydro-p2os-teleop/opt/ros/hydro/share/p2os_teleop/cmake/p2os_teleop-msg-paths.cmake
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:40 (FILE):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-p2os-teleop-1.0.1-0raring-20130723-0625/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/devel/include/p2os_teleop".


make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-p2os-teleop-1.0.1-0raring-20130723-0625/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
dh_auto_install: make -j1 install DESTDIR=/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-p2os-teleop-1.0.1-0raring-20130723-0625/debian/ros-hydro-p2os-teleop AM_UPDATE_INFO_DIR=no returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary] Error 29
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
E: Failed autobuilding of package
W: no hooks of type C found -- ignoring
I: unmounting /var/cache/pbuilder/ccache filesystem
I: unmounting dev/pts filesystem
I: unmounting proc filesystem
I: cleaning the build env 
I: removing directory /var/cache/pbuilder/build//19152 and its subdirectories
Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' marked build as failure
Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' marked build as failure
Description set:
```

---

Update: So I think I got it. The CMakeLists.txt file had some unnecessary stuff that made this a problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68278/jenkins-build-issues---file-install-cannot-find-/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-07-23**:
Weird, can you post an answer and accept for others who run into this?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-07-23**:
Sorry to be unclear... It's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking at your repository and packages here:

https://github.com/allenh1/p2os/tree/master/p2os_teleop

A few things:

- remove all `mainpage.dox` (this is for rosbuild only)
- remove all `manifest.xml` (this is for rosbuild only)
- remove all instances of these lines: (this was a hold over from rosbuild and should not be used anymore)

Example below.

```
# set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
# set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

Specifically for `p2os_teleop`, you call `generate_messages` but never declare any messages, you should remove that macro call. I think that will fix the above issue. I opened a ticket to get a better error message here:

https://github.com/ros/genmsg/issues/31

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-07-23**:
Thank you much!!! Worked like a charm.